# suitable generics to use in an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am using an `Arraylist` to hold heterogeneous data...a mix of `String`, `int` and `class` objects (These objects could be instances of any class I've defined.). I've initialised the `ArrayList` as    `ArrayList<Object> = new ArrayList<Object>`.

But I think I've heard ppl saying that directly referring to the Objects is sth. bad/undesirable? I'm referring to the objects because I can't find any suitable generics to use in my case. Is it ok to use or are there any suitable generics? (I'm relatively new to Java)

Comment: What are you doing with this list?  My first instinct is that there may be a flaw in design/intent, even though what you're doing is perfectly "legal".

Comment: I'm trying to return this list and any other method that retrieves this list would extract the items in it for further processing.

Comment: What processing will the client do to elements of such a list? It has to do this without any type specific knowledge.Is this what you have as your design?

Comment: i'm starting to realise now that there's indeed the design flaw in my program.....the client will retrieve the items and display into the swt tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different list for each type and keep those lists in a map and you can use the class object as the key so it wont mix up and easy to access.

```
 Map<Class<?>,List<?>> map = new HashMap<Class<?>,List<?>>();
 map.put(String.class, new ArrayList<String>());
 map.put(Integer.class, new ArrayList<Integer>());
 map.put(Class.class, new ArrayList<Class<?>>());
```

EDIT:

P.S: You will still get an unchecked warning when you retrieve the list from the map if you want to add new object into the list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Class<?>,List<?>> map = new HashMap<Class<?>,List<?>>();
        map.put(String.class, new ArrayList<String>());
        map.put(Integer.class, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        map.put(Class.class, new ArrayList<Class<?>>());

        String str = "deneme";

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<String> strList =  (List<String>) map.get(String.class);
        strList.add(str);
        strList.add("str2");
        strList.add("str2");

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Class<?>> classList =  (List<Class<?>>) map.get(Class.class);
        classList.add(String.class);
        classList.add(Integer.class);
        classList.add(Double.class);


        for(String currentStr:strList){
            System.out.println(currentStr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post a working example so that it becomes clearer as to why you are implementing it like the above said scenario.

Comment: @Deepak At one point you will still get an unchecked cast warning, when you retrieve the list from map, it will be List<?> , if you mean that. Map is there just to keep lists in an easyly accessible way and if you dont know how many and when you will need a List<T> of an unkown type T.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you put an `Object` as a generic classifier you'll end up with alot of ugly statements, like

```
if (elem instanceOf String)
else if (elem instanceOf Integer)
```

and so on. Often it's better to use a separate list for each, e.g.,

```
List<String> strings = new LinkedList<String>();
List<Integer> ints = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

Hence I would advice you to redesign your program to make better use of the features java fascilitates.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to use generics, if you don't know the type of target objects beforehand.

The compiler may give a warning, but what can good men do in such evil!

**Note**: You can actually use unbounded and wildcards to ignore the warning but I am not sure whether it will help otherwise.